# buffer.write() in Rust Language starting from write() in C

Tags: rust, rust-crates

I have this code in C that writes in a fd the command. My issue is that I can't represent the same behaviour in Rust language because apparently the `.write()` doesn't takes the same parameters as C's `write()`. The function is the following:

```c
static void set_address(int32_t fd, uint64_t start_address, uint64_t len){
    uint64_t command[3];
    int64_t bytes;

    command[0] = SET_ADDRESS_AREA;
    command[1] = start_address;
    command[2] = len;

    bytes = write(fd, command, (ssize_t)LEN_SET_ADDRESS_AREA);

    if (bytes != LEN_SET_ADDRESS_AREA)
    {
        printf("\nError\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
}
```

So my code is:

```rust
for (i,val) in ref_memory.iter().enumerate().step_by(DIM_SLICE){ 
                let mut start_address = val ; 
                
                let p = std::ptr::addr_of!(start_address);
                println!("the address index of val is {:?}",p);
                let mut command = (SET_ADDRESS_AREA,start_address,DIM_SLICE);
               
                let file_buffer = File::create(_path);
                let bytes_written = file_buffer.unwrap().write(command);
                }
             }
```

Writing this

```
let bytes_written = file_buffer.unwrap().write(command);
```

I get the error:

```
Mismatched types: expected reference &[u8] and found tuple (u8, &u8, u8)
```

Should I create a struct to pass just one reference of type &u8?

Alternatively, is there a crate that offers this feature?

Comment: Use [`libc::write()`](https://docs.rs/libc/latest/libc/fn.write.html) for equivalent of C's `write()`.

Answer (score 1):

Its not clear why you're diverged so much from the C code when converting it to Rust. Why the `for` loop? Why the `addr_of`? Why create the file in the function when the original clearly already has the file descriptor? Why create a tuple instead of an array?

The direct conversion is mostly straight-forward.

```
fn set_address(file: &mut File, start_address: u64, len: u64) {
    let command: [u64; 3] = [
        SET_ADDRESS_AREA,
        start_address,
        len
    ];

    let bytes = file.write(bytemuck::cast_slice(&command)).unwrap();

    if bytes != LEN_SET_ADDRESS_AREA {
        println!("Error");
        std::process::exit(-1);
    }
}
```

The only tricky part here is my use of the [bytemuck](https://crates.io/crates/bytemuck) crate to convert a `[u64]` into a `[u8]`. You can do without it, but is a bit more annoying.

Here is a full example on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2f0a61a05152bfb6a19f1e20aaaec336) that includes the above and two other methods.

Comment: IMHO using an external crate is a little bit more annoying than using `core::mem::transmute` 

Comment: @Miiao I would not typically suggest using `unsafe` to a Rust newcomer, *especially* not `transmute` which is incredibly easy to get wrong.

Comment: I create a Tuple because start_address is a type: &u8 differently from the others (u8).

Answer (score 0):

> Should I create a struct to pass just one reference of type &u8?

You don't need to create anything. write(2) takes 3 parameters because it needs an fd, a pointer to a buffer to write, and an amount of data to write.

In Rust, the `fd` is the object on which the method is called (`file_buffer`), and a slice (`&[u8]`) has a length so it provides both the "data to write" buffer and the amount of data to write.

What you should do is either just write `ref_memory` directly (it's not clear why you even split it across multiple writes, especially since you write them all to the same file anyway), or use [`chunks`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.chunks) to split the input buffer into sub-slices, that you can then write directly

> ```
> let p = std::ptr::addr_of!(start_address);
> ```

That makes absolutely no sense. That's a raw pointer to the `start_address` local variable, which is a copy of `val`.

Your C code is also... not right. Partial writes are perfectly valid and legal, there's lots of reasons why they might happen (e.g. hardware drivers, network buffer sizes, ...), a write(2) error is signalled by a return value of -1. Following which you'd generally read errno or use `perror(3)` or `strerror(3)` to report *why* the call failed.

Comment: i don't want writing the memory with the same file. 
The idea behind is to scroll down the memory in slice of 4kb and in each slice write the command.